# Codeigniter after export getting error in the excel. Message: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am using Codeigniter, when I click on the export button then I am getting my file to download and after download, I open my excel sheet and I am getting bellow errors. I tested below code an it's working on the localhost.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?
Filename: Shared/OLE.php
Line Number: 288
Backtrace:
File: /home/olpz2euas172/public_html/test/application/libraries/PHPExcel/Autoloader.php
Line: 79
Function: _error_handler
File: /home/olpz2euas172/public_html/test/application/libraries/PHPExcel/Autoloader.php
Line: 79
Function: require
File: /home/olpz2euas172/public_html/test/application/libraries/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php
Line: 169
Function: spl_autoload_call
File: /home/olpz2euas172/public_html/test/application/controllers/Report_control.php
Line: 64
Function: save
File: /home/olpz2euas172/public_html/test/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

I am using the below code in the controller. I am getting the correct data from my query.

```
public function export_employee_list(){

  $object = new PHPExcel();
  $object->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
  $table_columns = array("Firstname","Middlename","Lastname","Mobileno","Alternet no","Email Id","Address");
  $column = 0;
  $object->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('1:1')->getFont()->setBold(true);

  foreach($table_columns as $field)
  {
   $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, 1, $field);

   $column++;
  }
  $export_list = $this->Report_model->export_employee_list_model();
  $excel_row = 2;
  foreach($export_list as $row)
  {
   $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $excel_row, $row->firstname);
   $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $excel_row, $row->middlename);
   $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $excel_row, $row->lastname);
   $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, $excel_row, $row->mobileno);
   $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(4, $excel_row, $row->alternateno);
   $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(5, $excel_row, $row->email_id);
   $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(6, $excel_row, $row->address);

   $excel_row++;
  }

  $object_writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($object, 'Excel5');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Employee list.xls"');
        
        $object_writer->save('php://output');
        
        
 }
```

Comment: That is probably coming from PHPExcel which is no longer supported or recommended. Suggest you update your code to use (PHPSpreadSheet)[https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet] instead.

Comment: It caught the trailing closing brace accidently https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: @Dave, I was using these files in CodeIgniter https://prnt.sc/t9abkt

Comment: Yes, and PHPExcel is no longer supported and won't work correctly with the latest level of PHP. You need to change your use of it to use PHPSpreadsheet instead. You will need to modify your code.

Answer (score 0):

just open the files in a ascii editor like notepad++ by ftp goto the corresponding lines as mentioned in the error and change

In your case

_--------------------------

Filename: Shared/OLE.php

Line Number: 288

_-------------------------

continue; into continue 2;

It is really as easy as that.